# List error key is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, model-view-controller

I have this list in my ViewController in Asp.Net.

```
var Line1 = Skills.GroupBy(x => x.Line1).ToList();
```

This code gives me this result:

```
[0] ->  Key | "Software"
[1] ->  Key | "Consulting"
[2] ->  Key | "Hardware"
```

When I try to access this code in my view, it doesn't work.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Line1)
{
    var test = item.Key;
}
```

It says "Key is not defined". Why is that?

PS: I save the list into ViewBag.Line1 in my controller.

This is in the controller. If I type `Line1[0].Key`it gives me "Software".
[image]

But if I type item.Key it gives me the error mentioned above.

[image]

Comment: Another reason to never ever use this `ViewBag` et. al. stuff for anything other than the title of the page. Strongly typed models FTW.

Comment: So if it's a `List` then there's no property `Key`. `Key` is when you use `Dictionary`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am pretty new to Asp.Net, how would you do it? @UweKeim

Comment: are you trying to get the value or the index number of the list? What do you need the key for?

Comment: See the screenshots. I can access the .Key value in the controller but not in the view.

Comment: instead of using `var test = item.Key;` in your razor code use `@Key`

Comment: doens't work. It says Key is undefined @prospector

Comment: hmm, try `@item.Key`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **ViewModel** to solve this issue.

Just create a class that will hold your Line1 property,

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<IGrouping<string,Skill>> Line1{ get; set; }
}
```

Then create a strongly typed View with `MyViewModel` as the model. You can do this by just adding this at the top of your View file:

```
@model {YourModelNameSpace}.MyViewModel
```

Then pass the data from the controller to the view through the ViewModel, like this :

```
var myVm = new MyViewModel();
myVm.Line1 = Skills.GroupBy(x => x.Line1).ToList();

return View("YourViewName",myVm);
```

Hope this helps!